# Should each point be posted in a separate answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, faq-proposed

This is an issue in a lot of subjective questions but is relevant particularly here. Should people post large answers with lots of points or post each one in a separate answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the points are leading up to a common statement or sentiment, then one answer. If they are disjoint (such as multiple books in a book recommendation question or multiple people to follow on Twitter), one point per post so they can be voted on independently.