# Sidebar is FAQ'ed, lets update the FAQ tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Yes!  [The sidebar has been FAQed](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6910/faq-sidebar-on-programmers-meta)!

Our [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) has 18 questions in it while [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) has 40 more.  What questions should move there for easier access for people unfamiliar with the workings of meta?

I'd also mention that the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) has some rather dated material in it that *could* get a good looking over.... like [What should our FAQ contain?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2/) and [The Six Subjective Question Guidelines -- Enforcement Notice](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/350/) (which I hope we've largely come to accept) or [Why has this question converted to Community Wiki?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/941/) which is completely out of date.

Similarly https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1646/40980 should likely get a good look and update.

Comment: Let me be the first to say what we're all thinking:

"What the FAQ?!"

Answer (score 4):

These are all the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tagged questions at this time (sorted by newest).  Here's my take on what should be done with each one:

- [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) - It's good, though I'm probably biased.
- [A guide to moderating programmers.stackexchange yourself - close voting](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3059/a-guide-to-moderating-programmers-stackexchange-yourself-close-voting) - Its good
- [Contributing to the Blog](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/contributing-to-the-blog) - **Defaq it until the blog is active.  Alternatively, have someone who is active in the blog update it.**
- [Are software law questions off-topic here?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2099/are-software-law-questions-off-topic-here) - Ok
- [Are book recommendations on-topic?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/are-book-recommendations-on-topic) - Ok
- https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1646/faq-index-for-programmers-se - Ok though **should be updated** too.
- [Are "I'm looking for X" questions on topic?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1624/are-im-looking-for-x-questions-on-topic) - Ok.
- [Why is "what language should I learn" considered off-topic?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1573/why-is-what-language-should-i-learn-considered-off-topic) - Ok.
- https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1165/can-i-ask-career-advice-questions - Ok
- https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/what-types-of-programming-related-questions-are-off-topic (borderline) **Obsolete** - if not, it should be reopened.
- [What are the rules around moderators closing questions outright?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/855/what-are-the-rules-around-moderators-closing-questions-outright) - **Obsolete** - this is largely dating back from the great scope change and the contentions around that timeframe.
- [Are Career Advice questions useful to anyone except the poster?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/588/are-career-advice-questions-useful-to-anyone-except-the-poster) - Mostly **obsolete** (the two tags it mentions are gone) otherwise duplicate of https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1165/can-i-ask-career-advice-questions -- we really shouldn't have too many copies of the same question in the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq).
- [How do I get started with Programmers.SE?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/516/how-do-i-get-started-with-programmers-se) - Ok
- [The Six Subjective Question Guidelines -- Enforcement Notice](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350/the-six-subjective-question-guidelines-enforcement-notice) - **Obsolete** Yes, it was very important in its time, though this really isn't a  question anymore.
- [Are questions not directly related to programming (but might concern programmers) on-topic?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288/are-questions-not-directly-related-to-programming-but-might-concern-programmers) - **Obsolete** not an issue anymore.
- [What's the difference between Programmers and Stack Overflow?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171/whats-the-difference-between-programmers-and-stack-overflow) - **Rewrite and clean up**
- [What should our FAQ contain?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-should-our-faq-contain) **Obsolete**, so *very* obsolete.

---

So, from above:

These are the questions that should be dettaged:

- [Contributing to the Blog](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/contributing-to-the-blog)
- https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/what-types-of-programming-related-questions-are-off-topic
- [What are the rules around moderators closing questions outright?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/855/what-are-the-rules-around-moderators-closing-questions-outright)
- [Are Career Advice questions useful to anyone except the poster?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/588/are-career-advice-questions-useful-to-anyone-except-the-poster)
- [The Six Subjective Question Guidelines -- Enforcement Notice](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350/the-six-subjective-question-guidelines-enforcement-notice)
- [Are questions not directly related to programming (but might concern programmers) on-topic?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288/are-questions-not-directly-related-to-programming-but-might-concern-programmers)
- [What should our FAQ contain?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-should-our-faq-contain)

These questions should be updated:

- https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1646/faq-index-for-programmers-se
- [What's the difference between Programmers and Stack Overflow?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171/whats-the-difference-between-programmers-and-stack-overflow)

I will point out that the FAQ Index itself may instead be better to put in the tag wiki for [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) instead of having it be its own question.

Comment: I have made a slight adaptation to http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3059/a-guide-to-moderating-programmers-stackexchange-yourself-close-voting to update it with the correct close reasons. Otherwise, I agree with the assessments here.

Comment: For the rewrite of "What is the difference between Programmers and SO", we could borrow from http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in

Answer (score 3):

Lets go through [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed).  Note that a few of these are ones that I wrote.  I'll avoid making recommendations on them.  Many of these were issues that were FAQ issues back in earlier times when things were in more flux (scope and the help center about scope).  Many of these questions are now of historical oddity and while can serve as a record of where we've been, they aren't as useful for providing guidance to people *today*.  All of this is my take on the topic meant to start some activity on clear cut ones and considerations of the non-clear cut ones.

- [On discussions and why they don't make good questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6742/on-discussions-and-why-they-dont-make-good-questions) - Mine.
- [Should cross-posting be allowed sometimes on Programmers?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6665/should-cross-posting-be-allowed-sometimes-on-programmers) - More thought needed
- [I just failed an audit, but I was right and it was wrong. What now?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6625/i-just-failed-an-audit-but-i-was-right-and-it-was-wrong-what-now) - **FAQ it**
- [Why is research important?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important) - Mine
- [There seems to be some contradictory guidance with respect to asking career development questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6458/there-seems-to-be-some-contradictory-guidance-with-respect-to-asking-career-deve) - This is another career question and I'm of the opinion that we should have only one career question in the FAQ, and this isn't the one that fits the FAQ the best.
- [Why do certification questions keep getting closed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6442/why-do-certification-questions-keep-getting-closed) - Mine
- [Where to start?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start) - Mine
- [Why do interview questions make poor Software Engineering.SE questions?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6360/why-do-interview-questions-make-poor-programmers-se-questions) - Mine
- [How to ask a batch of related questions?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6327/how-to-ask-a-batch-of-related-questions) - More thought needed
- [Where does my git question go?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/where-does-my-git-question-go) - Mine
- [Current events - Questions and answers](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6283/current-events-questions-and-answers) - Mine
- [Is programming history on topic?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5633/is-programming-history-on-topic) - **FAQ it**
- [Adding the definition of a "shopping list/request" to the FAQ](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3547/adding-the-definition-of-a-shopping-list-request-to-the-faq) - **Obsolete** (detag it)
- [Changing the FAQ to reflect the site's name](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3301/changing-the-faq-to-reflect-the-sites-name) - **Obsolete** (detag it).  See above
- [What's all this about heroic edits?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3096/40980) - **FAQ it**  Consider a name change.
- [How should I go about getting rid of bad tags en masse?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2959/40980) - **Obsolete** (detag it)
- [Should "legal advice" or "copyright, trademark, and patent law" be added to the list of things this site is not about?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2912/should-legal-advice-or-copyright-trademark-and-patent-law-be-added-to-the) - **Obsolete** (detag it)
- [How can Programmers.SE be used to assist students with class assignments?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2894/40980) - More thought needed
- [Addendum to off topic themes in the FAQ](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2856/addendum-to-off-topic-themes-in-the-faq) - **Obsolete** (detag it)
- [Basic guidelines for discussing business logic and programming](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2699/basic-guidelines-for-discussing-business-logic-and-programming) - More thought needed
- [Are "what did <person> mean" questions on topic?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/are-what-did-person-mean-questions-on-topic) - I think that [Discuss this ${blog}](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6417/40980) is a better analysis of the issue, but thats my post too.
- [Are "Why is X code snippet done this way?" questions on-topic?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2608/are-why-is-x-code-snippet-done-this-way-questions-on-topic) - **Obsolete**ish
- [Are "I need data on X phenomenon" questions on-topic?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2599/are-i-need-data-on-x-phenomenon-questions-on-topic) - **Obsolete** (part of a cleanup form '11)
- [Legal Disclaimer in the FAQ](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2590/legal-disclaimer-in-the-faq) - **Obsolete**
- [Are marketing questions on topic?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2502/are-marketing-questions-on-topic) - **Obsolete**
- [When should comments be deleted?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2228/when-should-comments-be-deleted) - More thought needed
- [FAQ should include examples of good questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2133/faq-should-include-examples-of-good-questions) - **Obsolete** (see the tour again)
- [How to reconcile guidelines, community opinion and moderation](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2131/how-to-reconcile-guidelines-community-opinion-and-moderation) - **Obsolete**
- [Are new users allowed to advise without mini-modding?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2114/are-new-users-allowed-to-advise-without-mini-modding) - Consider redoing as a new Q&A to address community moderation
- [How can we improve our guidance about the purpose of comments?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2044/how-can-we-improve-our-guidance-about-the-purpose-of-comments) - **Obsolete** as written it isn't that FAQy.
- [Why was my question closed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2015/why-was-my-question-closed) - I think [Why was my question closed or down voted?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted) does a better job of answering this, but thats my post.
- [Can something highlighting the difference between Programmers and SO be added to the FAQ?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1838/can-something-highlighting-the-difference-between-programmers-and-so-be-added-to) - **Obsolete** as written it isn't that FAQy.
- [When are career questions too localized? Should this be more strict?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1556/when-are-career-questions-too-localized-should-this-be-more-strict) - Another career question question.
- [Should each point be posted in a separate answer?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40/should-each-point-be-posted-in-a-separate-answer) - This is already partly in the help center in [What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)

Comment: I generally agree with the assessments (with the "Mine" annotation taken as "FAQ it"). The "More thought needed" mostly seem not FAQ-worthy to me.

Comment: I think all of your faq-proposed should be faq.